# 404 Error on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking, dns

I received a verification link from Omegle but whenever I click on it, I get this: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R9gHB.png). I was also getting the same error when I tried to go to www.omegle.com but managed to fix it by adding `www.omegle.com <45.56.77.214>` to my /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d file. However I am unable to go to www.chatserv.omegle.com by adding these lines `www.chatserv.omegle.com <104.200.19.224>`.

Those are the correct IP addresses for each website.

This is happening on all browsers.

Comment: Please don't add "Solved" to the title. See https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/7413/15003.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "This is happening on all browsers."

Well, that probably means one of three things:

- Your DNS is not configured correctly. Try setting your primary DNS to `8.8.8.8` and your secondary DNS to `8.8.4.4`
- It's the website's problem, not yours - You can test for this by using a different computer to browse to that website at a coffee shop or some other place with free internet. If you have the same problem, then you should contact the webmaster of the website and alert them to the issue.
- Your ISP is doing something sketchy (or something else not very obvious) - You can test for this by doing the same as the above. If you are able to get through to the website, then either your ISP is doing something sketchy, or the problem is being caused by something else that isn't very obvious.